# Calcium Hydroxide, 98%, extra pure + DI resulted in a bright pink solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

When combined with DI, my 98% calcium hydroxide resulted in a pink solution. I am trying to make limewater for a class demonstration and have only ever seen limewater as a colourless solution. Anyone else had this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Why [tag:organic-chemistry] tag? Is there an organic substance or indicator present in the solution? DI usually stands for "deionized". Deionized what, water? How clean was the glassware? Could you upload a photo and specify lighting conditions to eliminate possible light scattering effects?

Comment: Try different water ( even tap one ) and different glassware/vessel. Still pink ? If still pink then my educated guess says there must be a pink dye in the calcium hydroxide lot. If not there may be dye contamination of the vessel, possibly some phenolphthaleinum from prior activities.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, it seems a phenolphthaleinum contamination was the issue and subsequent attempt to make limewater have resulted in a clear solution. Thanks!

Comment: It's almost as if there were phenolphthalein in the solution.